# iOS - AVAudioSession Route Change Notification not work as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, avaudiosession

I have a app that can play sound. it works fine in usually. However when I Repeatedly disconnect and connect the Bluetooth headset, iPhone status bar shows the Bluetooth headset has been connected, and sound play is not in Bluetooth output route(maybe built-in receiver or speaker).

In my code, the last few disconnect and connect have not been notified from  `AVAudioSession Route Change Notification`. And I get current output route from `[[[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute] outputs] firstObject]`  is also not the bluetooth output.

Is this an issue of iOS? and Can I handle it with code? cause I want to play sound in a Bluetooth route in above case.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Which iOS version?